# How should I access to Viber contact image?

Tags: android, image, api, contacts, viber

I wanted to create an app to save contact image from Viber Application to my local contacts, for this purpose I need some access to the Viber app. Is this possible? 
If yes, Is there any way to now the relation between Viber image and Contact in Android?
Any API or some sort of these things.

Comment: Viber images are saved in a local folder ... There's no need to access viber app...

Comment: Yep, i know it, but i want to sync contact with the Viber image contact.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to send a message to groups of Viber using computer?

Comment: i don't understand, explain more plz